# Bluebird promise usage, does it leak?

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth, bluebird

I do not really understand the memory model in promises. I'm using Bluebird 2.x.

I have something like this which attempt to connect to a bluetooth device. I want it so that if it fails to connect within a 10 second period, I want to close it and return it as failure.

```
Control.prototype.connectToAddress = function connectToAddress(address)
{
  var self = this;

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
      reject(new Error('Timeout'));
    }, 10000);

    self.bt.connectToAddressAndService(address, self.service)
    .then(function(dev) {
      clearTimeout(timer)
      resolve(dev);
    })
    .then(function error(err) { reject(err); });

  });
}
```

This isn't the actual situation. The real situation is that `connectToAddress` is resolve immediately without waiting for device to connect. An emitter is set up later to notify the caller that a device is found. But for the sake of the question, suppose `connectToAddress` actually waits and return the connected device.

When we fail to connect to a device within 10 seconds, perhaps it moves away after we scanned it, the promise is rejected. But, `self.bt.connectToAddressAndService` call has not been resolved to either resolve or reject. If `connectToAddress` is repeatedly called in situation like this, does that cause some sort of memory stack to build up and never released? If so, what can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are just Javascript objects that are garbage collected just like any other Javascript object.  So, as long as you don't keep references to promises indefinitely, they will be garbage collected just like any other object when they are no longer being used.

So, in your specific example, the state you shown in your function will stay alive as long as your timer is still going or `.connectToAddressAndService()` is still doing something and might still be able to reject or resolve (meaning it still has live references to the resolve or reject handlers).  The timer obviously has a fixed life of 10 seconds.  But, you don't show the code that is behind `.connectToAddressAndService()` so we can't really offer any info on how long that might stay alive.  It really ought to be the case that it will either resolve or reject at some point so there's no chance it could hang out forever keeping this internal state alive.  We'd have to see the code inside of that to know if that is currently a problem or not.

If you've timed out your operation, but `.connectToAddressAndService()` is still alive and will call it's own resolve or reject handler some long time in the future, then there is memory still in use while it is waiting to eventually finish.  Even though the promise has already been rejected, Javascript doesn't know what your other code around `.connectToAddressAndService()` might be doing so the internal state in the code you show is kept alive and in memory.

Comment: 1) So, if `.connectToAddressAndService` never resolves or rejects, then not only has the memory space used in that function is kept alive, but `connectToAddress` is kept alive as well? 2) And if there is yet another call to this `.connectToAddress`, another memory space for the stack is again created?

Comment: @huggie - It depends upon exactly what is going on in `.connectToAddressAndService()`.  If it's holding legit references to things that could still run and could still resolve or reject (even if it never actually does), then yes it will keep everything else alive and can cause memory to not get freed.  It really depends upon the internals of `.connectToAddressAndService()`.